# How to prove/show that the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$ is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to prove/show that the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$ is decreasing?
My idea:

- $n^2<(n+1)^2 /+1$
- $n^2+1<(n+1)^2+1/ \sqrt{}$
- $\sqrt{n^2+1}<\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}/+n$
- $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n<\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}+n$

And now I'm stuck since if I add 1 to the both sides, I don't know how to move it from the right side without also moving it from the left side.

Comment: I do not understand first line in your idea.. what does $/ +$ mean?

Comment: Can't this be proved by induction on $n$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik With that I meant what I'm doing to the both sides of the inequality: add 1 to the both sides, take the square root to the both sides...

Comment: @Nick : I guess that is not a general notation... It would be better if you actually write that in body of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to show that the sequence of denominators, $\sqrt{1+n^2} + n$, is increasing, since if the denominators increase while the numerators stay the same, the fractions decrease.

We want to show $$\color{darkred}{\sqrt{1+n^2}} + \color{darkblue}{n} < \color{darkred}{\sqrt{1+(n+1)^2}} + \color{darkblue}{(n+1)}.$$  It is enough to show $\color{darkblue}{n < n+1}$ and $\color{darkred}{\sqrt{1+n^2} < \sqrt{1+(n+1)^2}}$.  The first is immediate.  Because $\sqrt x$ is an increasing function of its argument, it is enough to show $$\begin{align}1+n^2 & < 1+(n+1)^2 \\& = 1 + n^2+2n+1\end{align}.$$ Since $n$ is a positive integer, $2n+1$ is positive and we are done.

(This "increasing function" argument is used constantly, and you should make sure you understand it.  If $f(x)$ is an increasing function, then $x>y$ implies $f(x) > f(y)$ and vice versa.  Then if we want to show $f(x) > f(y)$, it is enough to show $x>y$.  In this example, $f(x) = \sqrt x$.  We used the same argument in reverse at the beginning of the answer: since $f(x)= \frac 1x$ is a *decreasing* function, to show $\frac1x<\frac1y$ it suffices to show that $x>y$.)

(Note also that we could have used this same argument to show that $1+n^2 < 1+(n+1)^2$ instead of the algebraic argument I used above. For positive $n$, the function $1+n^2$ is an increasing function of $n$, so to show $1+n^2 < 1+(n+1)^2$ it suffices to show that $n< n+1$, which needs no proof.)

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to see *( for example we calculate their derivative)* that the functions
$$x\mapsto x^2+1\quad;\quad x\mapsto \sqrt x\quad;\quad  x\mapsto x$$
are increasing on $[0,+\infty)$ hence the function 
$$x\mapsto \sqrt{x^2+1}+x$$
is also increasing as composition and sum of increasing functions hence the function
$$f\colon x\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}$$
is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ since it's the inverse of increasing function. Now what we can say about the monotonicity of the sequence
$$a_n=f(n)\qquad?$$

Answer (score 2):

You have to prove $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}+n+1}$$

i.e., $$\sqrt{n^2+1}+n< \sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}+n+1$$

i.e., $$\sqrt{n^2+1}< \sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}+1$$

i.e., $$n^2+1< (n+1)^2+1+1+2(\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1})$$

i.e., $$n^2< (n+1)^2+1+2(\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1})$$

i.e., $$0 <2n+1+1+2(\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1})$$

i.e., $$0 <n+(\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1})$$

Can you conclude this and fill gaps in between?

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1) The sequence is decreasing if the denominators are increasing

2) $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n$ is increasing if both $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ and $n$ are increasing

3) $n$ is increasing. $\sqrt{n^2+1}>n$ is also increasing. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac1{\sqrt{1+n^2}+n}=\sqrt{1+n^2}-n$.

The sequence would be decreasing if $\sqrt{1+n^2}-n>\sqrt{1+{(n+1)}^2}-n-1\iff \sqrt{\color{grey}{0^2} +1^2}+\sqrt{1+n^2}>\sqrt{1+{(n+1)}^2}$ which is the triangle inequality or Schwarz inequality!.